# Data Binding to menu using multiple data types and being able to set the icon

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, menu

**Before you mark as duplicate, I have read the other SO entries, none seem to apply**

I have two classes, one for menu item groups which will comprise my root menu items, and one for the sub items as such

```
public class RootItem
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public image icon {get;set;}
    public List<SubItem> subItems {get;set;}
}

public class SubItem
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public image icon {get;set;}
}
```

The rest of what I am trying to do is probibly obvious but ill outline it anyway:

```
<MenuItem ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RootItems}" Header="Menu">
    <MenuItem.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type root:RootItem}">
            <DataTemplate.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding name}"/>
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding subItems}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding icon}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataTemplate.Resources>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type root:SubItem}">
            <DataTemplate.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding name}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding icon}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataTemplate.Resources>
        </DataTemplate>
    </MenuItem.Resources>
</MenuItem>
```

This is just one of the methods I tried, in this one it doesn't seem like the style is used at all as only the root items show but they are blank, no icon or name.

I must be able to use 2 separate classes and the icon must be set-able and there must be 2 data templates or styles to handle/show the 2 classes differently.

I have also tried this, which while a mess, gets me 90% of the way, I just have issues where the icon is only visible on the last menu item.

```
<MenuItem ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RootItems}" Header="Menu">
    <MenuItem.Resources>
        <imico:InputMapperIcon x:Key="ico" Icon="{Binding icon}" x:Shared="false"/>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type root:RootItem}" x:Shared="false" ItemsSource="{Binding subItems}">
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="MenuItem.Header" Value="{Binding name}"/>
                    <Setter Property="MenuItem.Icon" Value="{StaticResource ico}"/>
                    <Setter Property="MenuItem.Tag" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Menu}}, Path=DataContext}"/>
                    <EventSetter Event="MenuItem.Click" Handler="BtnAddCommand_Click"/>
                </Style>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </MenuItem.Resources>
    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="MenuItem.Header" Value="{Binding name}"/>
            <Setter Property="MenuItem.Icon" Value="{StaticResource ico}"/>
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: Is there a typo in your style's binding to ItemsSource? 'commands' instead of 'subItems'?

Comment: @sfm no, just a typo here, I wrote some pseudo code to illustrate what I was doing to save from the pages of likely irrelevant info.

Comment: do you have the problem with missing icons even if you replace your InputMapperIcon with a simple <Image x:Key="test" Source="yourpath.bmp" x:Shared="False"> ?

Comment: @Milan As in my second example, I already set the `x:Shared` property.

Comment: im aware, i wanted you to try to remove your InputMapperIcon, because i think something inside it is causing your problem, so i wanted you to use a simple image instead

Comment: @Milan an issue inside that control woulden't be able to bubble up in this manner, it does the same with `<TextBlock x:Key="ico" Text="HI" x:Shared="false"/>`

Comment: i copied your lower xaml snippet, used a simple image instead of what you use, and i see an icon in every subitem i have...

Answer (score 0):

here is a working example, copied from your second xaml snippet:

.xaml

```
 <Grid Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RootItems}" Header="Menu">
                <MenuItem.Resources>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type root:RootItem}" x:Shared="false" ItemsSource="{Binding subItems}">
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style>
                                <Setter Property="MenuItem.Header" Value="{Binding name}"/>
                                <Setter Property="MenuItem.Icon" Value="{Binding icon}"/>
                            </Style>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </MenuItem.Resources>
                <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="MenuItem.Header" Value="{Binding name}"/>
                        <Setter Property="MenuItem.Icon" Value="{Binding icon}"/>
                    </Style>
                </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Grid.ContextMenu>
</Grid>
```

.cs

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<RootItem> RootItems { get; set; }
   public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RootItems = new ObservableCollection<RootItem>();
        var rootitem = new RootItem() { name = "rootitem" };
        rootitem.subItems = new List<SubItem>();
        var subitem = new SubItem() { name = "subitem" };
        subitem.icon = new Image();
        subitem.icon.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\username\source\repos\WpfApp3\WpfApp3\New Bitmap Image.bmp"));
        var subitem2 = new SubItem() { name = "subitem2" };
        subitem2.icon = new Image();
        subitem2.icon.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\username\source\repos\WpfApp3\WpfApp3\New Bitmap Image.bmp"));
        rootitem.subItems.Add(subitem);
        rootitem.subItems.Add(subitem2);
        RootItems.Add(rootitem);

        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
public class RootItem
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Image icon { get; set; } 
    public List<SubItem> subItems { get; set; }
}

public class SubItem
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Image icon { get; set; } 
}
```

so the mistake i imagine must be in how you assign image to your SubItem(which i removed in my example, i use a staticresource instead), or in your InputMapperIcon

Comment: I mentioned above, even using `<TextBlock x:Key="ico" Text="HI" x:Shared="false"/>` causes it to only appear in last menu item

Comment: that works perfectly aswell. the error is not in the code you posted so far

Comment: Your example isn't binding the icon, sorry but one of my requirements is having a bindable icon.

Comment: edited: now binding to the icon property of the SubItem. icon still works for every item

Comment: interesting, i think this may be style related, placed elsewhere in app and the icons work there.

Comment: well, if you can reproduce it in a simple example, i would love to bang my head on it a while. do share if you have found the problem

Comment: I will be banging my head on it this morning, I think it boils down to the fact that my apps default style overrides are target at types ie `{x:Type MeniItem}` and since this bound data is essentially a different type, the styling is not being applied. I have to figure out how to use the style in my code above on top of my bas application styles.